# Can't access jenkins user on server

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-14.04

Can't access the jenkins user on the server. Server currently running ubuntu 14.04, the user is available for a short period after a restart but is not accessible again after a few minutes.

All builds fail with message **Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure**

Restarting the service also fails as it cannot use the jenkins user that is specified on the server.

The jenkins user is setup to use bash and is available in /etc/passwd

Comment: You need to expand on what you mean by the user isn't available. You can't log in to the server as the user? Are you getting an error message? What is the error message from the build failure?

Comment: Generally to test any issues on the server, I switch users from the ubuntu user to jenkins user using the command sudo su - jenkins. Running the following command does not switch to the jenkins user. I can switch to other users that are available on the server except for the jenkins user.

Build failure message is: Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to sudo to the jenkins user? The Jenkins job build failure should have a stack trace associated with it. Look at the console output from the build.

Comment: Hi Adam

This is the last output from the console out:

rm -rf node_modules/
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE


Further more, there is no output when trying to switch to the jenkins user. It just reverts back to the ubuntu user without showing any errors

Comment: Weird. One more thing you might try looking at is the /var/log/secure file, and the /var/log/messages file to try to see why you can't su to the jenkins user.

Comment: I restarted the server and the builds seem to be working again.